# Printing Multiple Pages C#

Tags: c#, printing

I'm trying to print some text data using an event handler, and then print a PDF on the second page.

I'm using pdfium viwer to do this and it works individually. But I'm struggling to combine them.

I need to get the two to print as 2 pages of the same print document, as I want to use a duplex printer to print the pdf on the back. I don't just want to send two individual pages.

Sample code:
To Print PDF:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filena = @textBox1.Text;
    PrintPDF("M2020", "A4", filena, 1);
}

public bool PrintPDF(string printer, string paperName, string filename, int copies)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the printer settings for our printer
        var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
        {
            PrinterName = printer,
            Copies = (short)copies,
        };

        // Create our page settings for the paper size selected
        var pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings)
        {
            Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
        };
        foreach (PaperSize paperSize in printerSettings.PaperSizes)
        {
            if (paperSize.PaperName == paperName)
            {
                pageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Now print the PDF document
        using (var document = PdfDocument.Load(filename))
        {
            using (var printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
            {
                printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
                printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
                printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
                
                printDocument.Print();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my original code to print a QR code:

```
private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    string s2 = "Modified by: ";
    string s6 = "Author: " + author;
    string s4 = "Created: " + drawdate;
    QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator1 = new QRCodeGenerator();
    QRCodeData qrCodeDataPrint = qrGenerator1.CreateQrCode(qrcodedata, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q, false, false);
    Bitmap qrCodeImagePrint = (new QRCode(qrCodeDataPrint)).GetGraphic(20);
    Bitmap bmimg = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox2.Width, this.pictureBox2.Height);
    this.pictureBox2.DrawToBitmap(bmimg, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.pictureBox2.Width, this.pictureBox2.Height));
    System.Drawing.Font f1 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 5f, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
    System.Drawing.Font f2 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 2f, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
    System.Drawing.Font f3 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 3f, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
    System.Drawing.Font barc = new System.Drawing.Font("Code39Azalea", 36f, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1f);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(165, 35, 30, 30);
    Rectangle qrcodetest = new Rectangle(170, 40, 25, 25);
    Rectangle btmimg = new Rectangle(60, 140, 120, 120);
    Rectangle combox = new Rectangle(20, 145, 160, 40);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(qrCodeImagePrint, qrcodetest);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, qrcodetest);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(this.procreq, f1, Brushes.Black, new Point(50, 5));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s1, f1, Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 70));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s1z, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 75));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(qrissuedby, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 264));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s6, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 267));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s4, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 270));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s2, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 273));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s3, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 276));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s5, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 279));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(this.notebox.Text, f3, Brushes.Black, combox);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap1, btmimg);
    bmimg.Dispose();
    bitmap1.Dispose();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think i was going about that in completely the wrong way. What I eventually did was use the pdfium viewer to render the pdf as a bitmap, and then printed that as the second page.

```
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1f);
                
int actualwidth = (int)(e.Graphics.DpiX * 210 / 25.4f);
                int actualHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.DpiY * 297 / 25.4f);
                using (var pdfDocument = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(@textBox1.Text))
                {
                   var bitmapImage = pdfDocument.Render(0, actualwidth, actualHeight, false);
pictureBox1.Image = bitmapImage;
pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip((RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone));
                             }
    
if (pgnum == 1)
{
Debug.WriteLine("firing first page " + pgnum);
                    
Rectangle qrcodetest = new Rectangle(170, 40, 25, 25);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, qrcodetest);
e.HasMorePages = true;
pgnum++;
Debug.WriteLine(pgnum);
}
else
{
Debug.WriteLine("firing second page " + pgnum);
GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 199, 281);
//e.Graphics.Q
e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, srcRect);
     
e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

This does work.... but the printed version of the PDF is very poor quality. I've tried using interpolation etc.... but doesn't seem to make any difference, so not sure i'm putting it in the right place?

Also, i've tried using the bitmap variable rather than the picturebox image, but it seems to generate the same result. The PDF prints much better.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Actually, the QR code was printing fine. What I was having a problem with was the pdfium rendered bitmap file. I was changing the DPI and it wasn't doing anything. But it looks like you have to add a flag to this: var bitmapImage = pdfDocument.Render(0, 300, 300, PdfRenderFlags.CorrectFromDpi);